# how send cacls command through FTP?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

In a goddady hosting,the files manager not allows to change permissions. Using FTP command `SITE CHMOD MASK FILE` don't works, obviously.

I read that windows has its own command, called *CACLS*

I tried to send the command manually using `SITE CACLS [...]` but don't works.

How I can change the permissions?

if my attempt is on the way to do it, what is the proper syntax?

The server responds with *220 Microsoft FTP Service*.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> CACLS myfile.txt /E /G "Everyone":F

It's the same as chmod 777